# Using Paid Fonts As Web Font

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

My client want to use a paid font (Futura) on website. We will purchase Futura but i have a question. When i purchase the font, is it possible to convert it to *webfont* to use on my website? Or it's forbidden because of licenses ? Or are there another ways to use Futura on our website.

(*I found a [link](https://typekit.com/fonts/futura-pt) for Futura Webfont, but i'm not sure is it what we are looking for.*)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for legal recommendations. We are all programmers- so most of us can't give you real legal advice. Perhaps you should contact the creators of Futura- they would probably give you the best advice.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

After a few conversations , i decided to use TypeKit. When i purchase a TypeKit account, i'll be able to use Futura as a webfont without any license problem. So if you experience same problem with me, and looking for answer you can purchase a TypeKit , or you can purchase **Web use** license for your font from myfonts.com